# Cast string to version in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm doing some work that requires identifying versions of installed software.  It comes back an array and the `version` attribute being a string. The formatting is correct.

```
$products = get-wmiobject Win32_Product....
$products.Version.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name         BaseType
-------- -------- ----         --------
True     True     String       System.Object
```

And a sample of the version string.. `18.0.102.14`

It should be simple to cast this over but I'm not seeing a ready way.

Comment: `[Version]'18.0.102.14'`

Comment: @KenWhite erm no.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TimBrigham: Oops. Misread the post and commented too soon. Glad I didn't post an answer of some sort. :-) Thanks for the correction.